# How to encrypt and salt the password using BouncyCastle API in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, salt

I am fairly new to *cryptography* and I am using `BouncyCasetle API` to *encrypt* password and store it in the database. For *encryption* I am using `SHA-1` algorithm and I want to salt the password to prevent it agains dictionary attacks.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  And I assume that you are planning to store a hash which would be one-way rather than actually encrypting.

Comment: The problem is I cannot find a correct documentation where in I can understand whats happening using BouncyCastle I have been trying to use PBEParametersGenerator and use its pbeParamGen.init(passwordBytes, salt, iterations);

Comment: Also consider to use the SRP-Protocol (Secure Remote Password Protocol) instead of storing hashed passwords.

Comment: @Puce, thanks for the heads-up on SRP.  I'm frankly shocked I hadn't heard of it yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend use of a Password-Based Key Derivation Function instead of a basic hash function for this.  Something like this:

```
// tuning parameters

// these sizes are relatively arbitrary
int seedBytes = 20;
int hashBytes = 20;

// increase iterations as high as your performance can tolerate
// since this increases computational cost of password guessing
// which should help security
int iterations = 1000;

// to save a new password:

SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
byte[] salt = rng.generateSeed(seedBytes);

Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator kdf = new Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator();
kdf.init(passwordToSave.getBytes("UTF-8"), salt, iterations);

byte[] hash =
    ((KeyParameter) kdf.generateDerivedMacParameters(8*hashBytes)).getKey();

// now save salt and hash

// to check a password, given the known previous salt and hash:

kdf = new Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator();
kdf.init(passwordToCheck.getBytes("UTF-8"), salt, iterations);

byte[] hashToCheck =
    ((KeyParameter) kdf.generateDerivedMacParameters(8*hashBytes)).getKey();

// if the bytes of hashToCheck don't match the bytes of hash
// that means the password is invalid
```

Comment: while storing into the database, should I encode the byteArray using Base64 and while getting back should I decode using the same used Base64? The password being varchar cannot store byteArray and I am finding difficulties in storing the values into varbinary.

Comment: @Zingo, Base64 is exactly intended for stuffing binary data into character fields.  However, **do not** perform the hash equality check inside your SQL database, since Base64 is case-sensitive and `varchar` types often are not.  Instead, since you have to retrieve the row to get `salt` anyway, fetch `hash` at the same time and do the comparison in Java.

Comment: Thanks (: for your inputs I just checked it did work thanks any links you can provide where I can have a thorough documentation of the API's used in BouncyCastle.

Comment: @Zingo, are you looking for the [javadoc](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html) or the [guide](http://www.cryptoworkshop.com/guide/)?

Comment: thanks I was looking for some Guide. Thanks a ton again for you inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

Well what you could do is get a:

```
StringBuilder salt=new StringBuilder();
salt.append("MySuperSecretSalt");
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
String text = "This is text to hash";
salt.append(text);    
md.update(salt.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")); // Change this to "UTF-16" if needed
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

Your, digest now contains the hash of your string+salt so it help with protecting against rainbow tables.

Comment: *Nota bene:* using a constant string essentially defeats the purpose of a salt.  The salt needs to be unique for each hashed password in order to prevent a single password guess from being mass-compared to the entire table.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your inputs, I have to use BouncyCastle API is there any document that you can point me to where in I can get the same equivalent of the code that you just used.

Comment: @JeffreyHantin I will be generating random salt and storing the same salt so that I can use it for decrypting when needed. Is that the right approach?

Comment: @JeffreyHantin You are right ,i just wanted to show an easy example. Cheers

Comment: @Zingo if you wan't to decode the data ,that you don't want to use hash-es you should be using something like AES ,with a secure key that you could get from a hash for example.