# Getting different encrypted password and salt while storing and retrieving from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to encrypt the password using a salt and storing it into the MySQL database.
I referred to this [stackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565369/how-to-encrypt-and-salt-the-password-using-bouncycastle-api-in-java/21565611?noredirect=1#comment32573081_21565611)

My code is similar to this:

```
private byte[] encrypt(String passwordToSave, byte[] salt)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        int seedBytes = 20;
        int hashBytes = 20;

        int iterations = 1000;

        if(null == salt)
        {
            SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
            salt = rng.generateSeed(seedBytes);
        }
        PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator kdf = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator();

        kdf.init(passwordToSave.getBytes("UTF-8"), salt, iterations);

        byte[] hash =
            ((KeyParameter) kdf.generateDerivedMacParameters(8*hashBytes)).getKey();
        return hash;        
    }
```

I just altered the function little to make use of it for both the purposes.

1. Encrypt the password while creating the user account and store it with the salt.
2. Encrypt the user password with the stored salt from database when he is trying to logging in and check it with the stored value of password.

The issue with this is,
I am not getting back what I stored.
I used a lot of different things,

1. I used `Base64` for encoding and stored into DB and decoded using the same while getting it back.
2. I tried to use `VARBINARY` and `BLOB` to save the byte[] data but no luck.
3. Then I used `VARCHAR` and just stored the `byte[]` by creating a new String from it using `"UTF-8"` encoding type.

I am new to cryptography so if I am wrong, please point it out.
Thanks in advance. :)

EDIT:

The output when I ran the encrypt twice:

```
Salt : [34, 17, -80, -59, 93, -90, 37, -25, -11, -43, 44, 1, 10, 7, -66, -108, 97, 36, 95, -116]
First Attempt: [-76, -3, 114, -69, 78, 21, -59, 23, 127, -15, 114, -106, -52, 23, 34, 91, 123, 6, 76, -115]
Second Attempt: [-76, -3, 114, -69, 78, 21, -59, 23, 127, -15, 114, -106, -52, 23, 34, 91, 123, 6, 76, -115]
Salt : [34, 17, -80, -59, 93, -90, 37, -25, -11, -43, 44, 1, 10, 7, -66, -108, 97, 36, 95, -116]
```

Comment: Are you storing the salt as well? And then when you encrypt the second time are you using the same salt? If you're encrypting with a different salt each time, you *will* get different results...

Comment: Yes I am saving the salt as well. I am getting different values from database only.

Comment: Okay, so take the database out of the equation completely - just call `encrypt` twice in a row with the exact same parameters, and then display the byte array output.

Comment: @JonSkeet : I simply sysout the byte[]. Is it okay??

Comment: Well no, that won't show you the bytes - it will just print something like `[B@6d6de4e1` which doesn't indicate the *content* of the array at all. Base64 encode it, or use `Arrays.toString(byte[])`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think I am doing something terribly wrong while storing the data. The encryption seems working.

Comment: Okay, so that's the next part to concentrate on. Use hard-coded data so that you're *only* looking at the storage part. You might want to delete this question, then ask another one which is just about the storage when you've got more information.

Comment: Ok I will. but what is the standard practice anyway? how can we store byte[] into mysql??

Comment: The first two methods you mention in the question should be okay. Do *not* try to interpret the hash as UTF-8-encoded text - it simply isn't.